# How to export my java application that is linked to sql server to an exe file?

Tags: java, sql-server, installation

I finished my application and now i want to use it in other computers. It is linked to sql server database, so the question is, how can i export it to a file than can be installed in other computers, and all the informations to be stored in a file? I exported it to jar file but it only works in my computer because of my sql server. I searched for this thing but I didnt find any question that fits my question.

Comment: a properties file maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with @ScaryWombat. When you distribute a program which require some configuration and you want those configuration to be changed and configured based on the target environment you want to include a mechanism for that.

A simple approach , if you have one or two configuration, those can be implemented to be read from the command line argument parsing.

if there are too many in that case you want to make use of property files.

In either case, i always suggest people to distribute their software application with a following directory structure as a package.

```
basepackage_folder
--- bin ( place executable scripts here )
--- lib ( place the libraries here )
--- log ( folder to log your application logging messages )
--- etc ( place for configuration files )
--- README ( A file which is helpful for end user of your program on how to install and run )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sql server is local to the machine running the application (i.e. not a shared server at a single company), then you'll have to provide that database as part of the installation of your app/jar file, and the user will have to have SQL Server installed (perhaps the express edition).  If that's the case, have you considered using Derby or Sqlite instead?

If the server is shared and everyone running your application will be able to connect to it, a properties file to hold the connection information makes sense.